# remove last character in id attribute

Tags: jquery

I am trying to remove the last character from a div id using jQuery.  Currently I have:

```
    <div id="foo/"></div>
```

But I need:

```
    <div id="foo"></div>
```

The character is always a `/` and is generated automatically (re:annoyingly) by the CMS I am using.  Having the `/` there is messing up some JavaScript linking I am trying to do.

How do I correct this issue?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Its easy by using the `attribute$=` CSS3 selector which means "ends with" in your jQuery selection:

```
$("div[id$=/]").each(function(){ 
    this.id = this.id.substr(0,this.id.length - 1);
});
```

**Edit:** Using Adobe® Browser Lab, I tested this code in IE6, IE7, Firefox 2.0 and Firefox 3.0, Safari 3.0. I have also tested locally in Safari 4.0 and Firefox 3.5. In all browsers it worked properly, and removed the trailing `/` from the id.

Comment: +1 nice, is that also mean, ^ is startswith and * means include?

Comment: Yes it does. It can handle most of the CSS3 selectors, plus jQuery adds a few more.

Comment: cool, I found this http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/ too, I should give it a try.

Comment: Worked wonderfully! Thank you so much for such and elegant little piece of code! That CSS ends with selector is something I didn't even know existed! Epic find :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

You can select all the divs that have an id attribute, and check if the `/` character is present at the end, and then remove it:

```
$('div[id]').each(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if (id.indexOf('/') == id.length-1) {
      $(this).attr('id', id.slice(0, -1));
      // or $(this).attr('id', id.substring(0, id.length-1));
    }
});
```

Comment: You really should use `id$=/` to match only those items. And `$(this).attr('id')` should be `this.id`. Creating a new jQuery object and calling a function `attr` is not the best/fastest way of getting/editing the id.

Comment: @dcneiner, I thought about that, but since the `/` character is not valid for the ID attribute, he might have unexpected behavior on different browsers by using that selector... http://is.gd/536C6

Comment: I realize it is invalid, but jQuery is treating it as any other attribute at that point, and the `/` didn't need to be escaped in my tests, though it still worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$("div").each(function(){
    var i=$(this).attr("id");
    if(i){
         i = i.substr(0,i.length-1);
         $(this).attr("id",i);
    }
});
```

Comment: There could be 100 divs that are fine on the page. It would be more efficient to use a more detailed jQuery selector so you end up looking through less items.

Answer (score 0):

This might do it:

```
$('*').each(function(){
  $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id').replace(/\/$/, ''));
});
```

Replace the `*` with `div` or any css selector supported by jquery.